# Manually create markers like git merge with conflict from a diff

Tags: git

When a `git merge` conflict occurs, markers like the following appear:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD:file.txt
Hello world
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> master:file.txt
```

Imagine if I have `file.txt`, and I manually edit it from

```
Hello world
```

to

```
Goodbye
```

I get the following when I do a git diff (with the default pager):

```
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index 802992c..2b60207 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Hello world
+Goodbye
```

Is there a way I can convert this format into the format given above with conflict markers in place for all changes? (It doesn't matter if it overwrites the file.)

Comment: When conflict occurs there are three files - Base, A and B, so you have such markers show a three way diff. Usual diff only shows difference between two files. So, not sure what are you expecting

Comment: There are git mergetools that perform a two-way merge, which may be what you want rather than simulating the conflict markers of a 3-way merge.  That said, the output of the conflict markers using an empty file as the base isn't entirely useless.  But you might want to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, you are right - I need a base. I would want to treat the common lines as the base, and the subtracted lines from the diff as new lines from the left commit, and the added lines from the diff as new lines from the right commit. Does that make sense?

Comment: (In that case, the markers showing the base will always be empty, in the case of a 3-way commit)

Comment: You could check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043063/annotated-diff-file-with-mine-and-yours-type-markers but it is for `diff` stand-alone command. I don't see any straight-forward way to tie it with `git diff`, but it is possible with some bash-magic.

Comment: That's really cool, @kan. I couldn't find similar options in `git diff`, but I found a different solution that works.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way - the following commands will turn a diff that looks like this:

```
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index 2b34ae8..a27a6bd 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1,16 +1,16 @@
 Line 1
+Addition here
 Line 2
 Line 3
 Line 4
 Line 5
 Line 6
 Line 7
-Line 8
+Line 8 Change here, and deletion on line 15
 Line 9
 Line 10
 Line 11
 Line 12
 Line 13
 Line 14
-Line 15
 Line 16
```

Into a file that looks like this:

```
Line 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
Addition here
>>>>>>> temp
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
<<<<<<< HEAD
Line 8
=======
Line 8 Change here, and deletion on line 15
>>>>>>> temp
Line 9
Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
Line 13
Line 14
<<<<<<< HEAD
Line 15
=======
>>>>>>> temp
Line 16
```

The commands and explanation are:

```
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)                # Get the current branch name
git checkout --orphan temp                             # Change to a branch with no parents, so to force a merge conflict
git add -A                                             # Add everything there
git commit -m 'temp'                                   # Commit
git checkout "$branch"                                 # Go back to your previous branch
(git merge --allow-unrelated-histories temp || true)   # Merge the unrelated branches, which causes a conflict with your changes. This is done in a subshell with the '|| true' so that it doesn't return an error code - I have this in a git alias, so this is necessary for me so the command isn't aborted halfway.
git add -A                                             # Add your conflict markers as additions to the file
GIT_EDITOR=true git merge --continue                   # Commit. When --continue is used it doesn't accept the flag --no-edit, so to stop git opening an editor for the commit message, use the command 'true' as the editor.
git reset HEAD^                                        # Get rid of the last commit but keep its changes (the markers). This is needed because there is no way to get out of a conflicting merge commit but keep the conflict markers.
git branch -D temp                                          # Clean up
```

You can of course make a script or an alias out of this. Note that it treats staged and unstaged changes the same.

Comment: Any way to do this without stashing unstaged changes and unstaging staged changes?

Comment: I'm unsure exactly what you want here, but this will make conflict markers for every change made since the last commit, so anything you don't want conflict markers for should be in a side commit (or stash)

Comment: The last line uses a `b` alias, which should be the `branch` subcommand. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to fix it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to generate git merge conflict files. It isn't an exact answer to the question, as it relies upon you having access to `a/file.txt` and `b/file.txt`.

You can though produce either file if you have the other file, and the diff, using `patch`.

And then it may be that this `git merge-file` command will produce the output you need:

```
touch /tmp/empty && git merge-file -L a/file.txt -L B -L b/file.txt -p a/file.txt /tmp/empty b/file.txt
<<<<<<< a/file.txt
Hello world
=======
Goodbye
>>>>>>> b/file.txt
```